# Azure Log Analytics: How to display AppServiceConsoleLogs AND AppServiceHTTPLogs together?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics

I can run the 2 queries below to view the logs for a certain time, separately.

`AppServiceConsoleLogs | where TimeGenerated >= datetime('2021-04-10 14:00')`

`AppServiceHTTPLogs | where TimeGenerated >= datetime('2021-04-10 14:00')`

How do I combine these into a single query to view the logs together?

Comment: Are you looking for a simple union? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not clear on how to use that properly. If I do `AppServiceHTTPLogs | union AppServiceConsoleLogs` then the results only contain the information that is common to both sources, e.g. TimeGenerated, Type, etc.  The rest of the information is blank and there are no actual messages

Answer (score 1):

The [union operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuremonitor) does the job to show all records from the specified tables.

I used the query below and no the problems you mentioned:

```
union requests, traces
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
```

The screenshot of the query result:

[image]

If you still have the problem, please share us the screenshot and more detailed info.